# HTML Editor not working in publishing pages - SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint, publishing

I am developing a SharePoint publishing portal wherein I make use of HTML Editor(third party control) in my page layout for editing the contents.

When I try to edit the page using the publishing console, the HTML Editor which I have added in my page doesn't appear at all. I monitored the design at run time using firebug and it showed no content. Where could I be wrong?

Regards,
Raghuraman.V

Comment: need mroe info. Which 3rd part control? does it apper for other pages? Any screenshots?

Comment: I use Telerik's Rad Editor. It doesn't appear in any of the pages. Even I tried with SharePoint's default HTML Editor. It didn't work out too.

Comment: Have you added in the control tags onto the page layout like so?: <telerik:RadHtmlField id="Content" FieldName="Page Content" runat="server" DisplayHeight="350" DisplayWidth="400"></telerik:RadHtmlField>

Answer (score 0):

As this happens with the default editor as well, I'd look outside of the control for the problem - possibly a JS error, or the field name is incorrect, i.e. make sure your page's content type actually has that field.